# Update labeling expression and properties with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

With PyQGIS API, I need to set labeling expression and text color dynamically before exporting the map to different file formats using `QgsLayoutExporter`.

The code I use:

```
layerTree = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
mapLayers: list[QgsMapLayer] = layerTree.layerOrder()
for mapLayer in mapLayers:
    if isinstance(mapLayer, QgsVectorLayer):
        labeling = mapLayer.labeling()
        if isinstance(labeling, QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling):
            settings = labeling.settings()

            format = settings.format()
            format.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
            settings.setFormat(format)

            settings.fieldName = f"'*' + {settings.fieldName} + '*'"
            labeling.setSettings(settings)
            mapLayer.triggerRepaint()

# export the map here
```

My problem is the expression set to `settings.fieldName` is not applied in my map export. Even after execution, I see the expression in QGIS labeling dialog, but I have to hit Enter or Tab to see the modification on the map. So, I might need to call a refresh function to apply this settings to the layer and the map.

The red color is well applied to the map export.

Note that I am looking for a full dynamic solution and I don't want to edit my data or create a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/167176/26949 I had to set `settings.isExpression = True` after setting fieldName, to let QGIS validate and apply the expression.